# Using Video.Screen instead of Surface object in SdlDotNet

Tags: c#, sdl, sdl.net

Every SDL or SdlDotNet tutorial I have seen has used a defined Surface as the main screen. For example

```
private static Surface videoscreen;
videoscreen = SetVideoMode(800, 600, 16, false, false, false, true);
videoscreen.Fill(Color.Black);
videoscreen.Blit(sprite);
videoscreen.Update();
```

However, while trying to build a game with SdlDotNet I noticed that I can simply use Video.Screen for any action I normally would have preformed on the Surface screen. For example:

```
Video.SetVideoMode(800, 600, 16, false, false, false, true);
Video.Screen.Fill(Color.Black);
Video.Screen.Blit(sprite);
Video.Screen.Update();
```

Is there a reason why everyone still uses a defined Surface? I'm assuming there is some sort of performance or stability issue that I haven't encountered within the scope of my little game, but I would like to know in case I might run into trouble later on.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old but! If you're still interested, here's my take on the subject:

The `Surface` objects returned by the `Video.SetVideoMode()` method and the `Video.Screen` property are not equal but they both use the same Handle, which is the pointer to the graphical data.
I would say it's mostly a matter of style, both are valid ways to work on your main display surface.

- `Video.SetVideoMode()` leads to the following in Video.cs:

  ```
  public static Surface SetVideoMode(int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel, bool resizable, bool openGL, bool fullScreen, bool hardwareSurface, bool frame)
  {
      /* ... */
      return new Surface(Sdl.SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, bitsPerPixel, (int)flags), true);
  }
  ```

  ... calling the following internal constructor in Surface.cs:

  ```
  internal Surface(IntPtr handle, bool isVideoMode)
  {
      this.Handle = handle;
      this.isVideoMode = isVideoMode;
  }
  ```
- Alternatively, this is the `Video.Screen` property definition in Video.cs:

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the surface for the window or screen,
  /// must be preceded by a call to SetVideoMode
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>The main screen surface</returns>
  public static Surface Screen
  {
      get
      {
          return Surface.FromScreenPtr(Sdl.SDL_GetVideoSurface());
      }
  }
  ```

  ... calling the following internal factory method in Surface.cs:

  ```
  internal static Surface FromScreenPtr(IntPtr surfacePtr)
  {
      return new Surface(surfacePtr);
  }
  ```

  ... in turn calling the following internal constructor in Surface.cs:

  ```
  internal Surface(IntPtr handle)
  {
      this.Handle = handle;
  }
  ```

If you compare the Handles of the `Surface` objects returned by `Video.SetVideoMode()` and `Video.Screen`, you will see that they are equal, which is all you need to know to make sure that you are actually working with the same data.

Hope this helps!

Sources:

https://www.assembla.com/code/lightcs/subversion/nodes/trunk/sdldotnet-6.1.0/source/src/Graphics/Video.cs?rev=4

https://www.assembla.com/code/lightcs/subversion/nodes/trunk/sdldotnet-6.1.0/source/src/Graphics/Surface.cs?rev=4